Is there a way apart from chunking of Dask to avoid excessive RAM usage due to large dataset?
I am using the following code to calculate some speed-related variables for a dataset that consists of about 200 million rows. In order to avoid Memory issues, I am using chunking.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.stats import skew, kurtosis
from tqdm import tqdm
import gc  # For garbage collection

# Read the joined DataFrame
joined_df = pd.read_parquet('joined_data.parquet')

# Fill NaN values in 'final_direction' with a placeholder
joined_df['final_direction'].fillna('Unknown', inplace=True)

# Define the road types and their corresponding whisker values
road_whiskers = {
    'motorway': {'lower_whisker': 32.0, 'upper_whisker': 162.0},
    'motorway_link': {'lower_whisker': 32.0, 'upper_whisker': 162.0},
    'trunk': {'lower_whisker': 1.0, 'upper_whisker': 169.0},
    'trunk_link': {'lower_whisker': 1.0, 'upper_whisker': 169.0},
    'primary': {'lower_whisker': 0.0, 'upper_whisker': 113.0},
    'primary_link': {'lower_whisker': 0.0, 'upper_whisker': 113.0},
    'secondary': {'lower_whisker': 0.0, 'upper_whisker': 83.0},
    'secondary_link': {'lower_whisker': 0.0, 'upper_whisker': 83.0},
    'tertiary': {'lower_whisker': 0.0, 'upper_whisker': 74.0},
    'tertiary_link': {'lower_whisker': 0.0, 'upper_whisker': 74.0},
    'residential': {'lower_whisker': 0.0, 'upper_whisker': 55.0},
    'living_street': {'lower_whisker': 0.0, 'upper_whisker': 36.0},
    'unclassified': {'lower_whisker': 0.0, 'upper_whisker': 96.0}
}

# Custom aggregation function with dynamic threshold based on road type
def custom_agg(series, func, fclass=None, require_min_size=1, **kwargs):
    lower_threshold = road_whiskers[fclass]['lower_whisker']
    upper_threshold = road_whiskers[fclass]['upper_whisker']
    valid_series = series[(series >= lower_threshold) & (series <= upper_threshold)]
    if valid_series.size < require_min_size:
        return np.nan
    return func(valid_series, **kwargs)

# Wrapper function to process each chunk
def process_chunk(chunk):
    grouped_chunk = chunk.groupby(['final_osm_id', 'final_direction', 'Time_Interval'])
    chunk_result = grouped_chunk.apply(lambda x: pd.Series({
        'min_speed': custom_agg(x['Speed'], np.min, fclass=x['fclass'].iloc[0]),
        'max_speed': custom_agg(x['Speed'], np.max, fclass=x['fclass'].iloc[0]),
        'avg_speed': custom_agg(x['Speed'], np.mean, fclass=x['fclass'].iloc[0]),
        'median_speed': custom_agg(x['Speed'], np.median, fclass=x['fclass'].iloc[0]),
        'std_dev_speed_sample': custom_agg(x['Speed'], np.std, require_min_size=2, ddof=1, fclass=x['fclass'].iloc[0]),  # Sample std dev
        'std_dev_speed_population': custom_agg(x['Speed'], np.std, require_min_size=2, ddof=0, fclass=x['fclass'].iloc[0]),  # Population std dev
        'skewness_sample': custom_agg(x['Speed'], skew, require_min_size=3, bias=False, fclass=x['fclass'].iloc[0]),  # Sample skewness
        'skewness_population': custom_agg(x['Speed'], skew, require_min_size=3, bias=True, fclass=x['fclass'].iloc[0]),  # Population skewness
        'kurtosis_sample': custom_agg(x['Speed'], kurtosis, require_min_size=4, bias=False, fisher=True, fclass=x['fclass'].iloc[0]),  # Sample kurtosis
        'kurtosis_population': custom_agg(x['Speed'], kurtosis, require_min_size=4, bias=True, fisher=True, fclass=x['fclass'].iloc[0]),  # Population kurtosis
        'valid_entries': np.sum((x['Speed'] >= road_whiskers[x['fclass'].iloc[0]]['lower_whisker']) & (x['Speed'] <= road_whiskers[x['fclass'].iloc[0]]['upper_whisker']) & x['Speed'].notna()),  # Count of valid rows with speed within thresholds and not NaN
        'road_type': x['fclass'].iloc[0]  # Road type for each group
    })).reset_index()
    return chunk_result

# Get the unique combinations in the sample
unique_combinations = joined_df[['final_osm_id', 'final_direction', 'Time_Interval']].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

# Determine the number of chunks based on the unique combinations
chunk_size = 10000000  # Number of unique combinations per chunk
num_chunks = math.ceil(len(unique_combinations) / chunk_size)

# Initialize progress bar
pbar = tqdm(total=num_chunks)

# Process each chunk and save to Parquet
for i in range(num_chunks):
    # Get the unique combinations for the current chunk
    chunk_combinations = unique_combinations.iloc[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size]

    # Filter the original DataFrame based on these unique combinations
    chunk_df = joined_df.merge(chunk_combinations, on=['final_osm_id', 'final_direction', 'Time_Interval'], how='inner')

    # Process the chunk
    chunk_result = process_chunk(chunk_df)

    # Convert 'Unknown' back to NaN before saving (required for saving to parquet files)
    chunk_result['final_direction'].replace('Unknown', np.nan, inplace=True)

    # Save the processed chunk to a Parquet file
    output_file_name_3 = f'speed_stats_processed_chunk_{i}.parquet'
    chunk_result.to_parquet(output_file_name_3)

    # Clear memory
    del chunk_df, chunk_result
    
    # Update progress bar
    pbar.update(1)
    
    # Garbage collection to free up memory
    gc.collect()

# Close progress bar
pbar.close()

This code runs successfully, but it takes more than 4 days to complete.
To fasten things, I also tried using Dask (parallel processing), using the following code:
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import skew, kurtosis

# Read the joined DataFrame (Dask equivalent for reading Parquet files)
joined_ddf = dd.read_parquet('joined_data.parquet')

# Fill NaN values in 'final_direction' with a placeholder
joined_ddf['final_direction'].fillna('Unknown', inplace=True)

# Define the road types and their corresponding whisker values
road_whiskers = {
    'motorway': {'lower_whisker': 32.0, 'upper_whisker': 162.0},
    'motorway_link': {'lower_whisker': 32.0, 'upper_whisker': 162.0},
    'trunk': {'lower_whisker': 1.0, 'upper_whisker': 169.0},
    'trunk_link': {'lower_whisker': 1.0, 'upper_whisker': 169.0},
    'primary': {'lower_whisker': 0.0, 'upper_whisker': 113.0},
    'primary_link': {'lower_whisker': 0.0, 'upper_whisker': 113.0},
    'secondary': {'lower_whisker': 0.0, 'upper_whisker': 83.0},
    'secondary_link': {'lower_whisker': 0.0, 'upper_whisker': 83.0},
    'tertiary': {'lower_whisker': 0.0, 'upper_whisker': 74.0},
    'tertiary_link': {'lower_whisker': 0.0, 'upper_whisker': 74.0},
    'residential': {'lower_whisker': 0.0, 'upper_whisker': 55.0},
    'living_street': {'lower_whisker': 0.0, 'upper_whisker': 36.0},
    'unclassified': {'lower_whisker': 0.0, 'upper_whisker': 96.0}
}

# Define the custom aggregation function
def custom_agg(series, func, fclass, require_min_size=1, **kwargs):
    lower_threshold = road_whiskers[fclass]['lower_whisker']
    upper_threshold = road_whiskers[fclass]['upper_whisker']
    valid_series = series[(series >= lower_threshold) & (series <= upper_threshold)]
    if valid_series.size < require_min_size:
        return np.nan
    return func(valid_series, **kwargs)

# Apply the function to each group
def process_group(group):
    fclass = group['fclass'].iloc[0]
    result = {
        'min_speed': custom_agg(group['Speed'], np.min, fclass),
        'max_speed': custom_agg(group['Speed'], np.max, fclass),
        'avg_speed': custom_agg(group['Speed'], np.mean, fclass),
        'median_speed': custom_agg(group['Speed'], np.median, fclass),
        'std_dev_speed_sample': custom_agg(group['Speed'], np.std, fclass, require_min_size=2, ddof=1),
        'std_dev_speed_population': custom_agg(group['Speed'], np.std, fclass, require_min_size=2, ddof=0),
        'skewness_sample': custom_agg(group['Speed'], skew, fclass, require_min_size=3, bias=False),
        'skewness_population': custom_agg(group['Speed'], skew, fclass, require_min_size=3, bias=True),
        'kurtosis_sample': custom_agg(group['Speed'], kurtosis, fclass, require_min_size=4, bias=False, fisher=True),
        'kurtosis_population': custom_agg(group['Speed'], kurtosis, fclass, require_min_size=4, bias=True, fisher=True),
        'valid_entries': np.sum((group['Speed'] >= road_whiskers[fclass]['lower_whisker']) &
                                (group['Speed'] <= road_whiskers[fclass]['upper_whisker']) &
                                group['Speed'].notna()),
        'road_type': fclass
    }
    return pd.Series(result)

# Group by and compute statistics in parallel
result = (
    joined_ddf.groupby(['final_osm_id', 'final_direction', 'Time_Interval'])
    .apply(process_group, meta={
        'min_speed': 'float64',
        'max_speed': 'float64',
        'avg_speed': 'float64',
        'median_speed': 'float64',
        'std_dev_speed_sample': 'float64',
        'std_dev_speed_population': 'float64',
        'skewness_sample': 'float64',
        'skewness_population': 'float64',
        'kurtosis_sample': 'float64',
        'kurtosis_population': 'float64',
        'valid_entries': 'int64',
        'road_type': 'object'
    })
)

# Convert 'Unknown' back to NaN before saving
result = result.compute()  # Convert Dask DataFrame to Pandas DataFrame for manipulation
result['final_direction'].replace('Unknown', np.nan, inplace=True)

# Save the result to Parquet
result.to_parquet('trydask.parquet', engine='pyarrow', index=True)```.

However this code results in Memory error.
Is there something that I could do to fasten things up while not resulting to RAM errors? I am using a laptop with 8 physical cores, 16 logical processors and 32 GB RAM.
Is there space for code optimization, or it is simply out of my laptop capabilities?

What is the complete stacktrace you get? Maybe you should try with a LocalCluster, in order to better aprehend what is hapening. Your code is a bit complex, and there is no reproducer, one thing I notice is that in the serial case, you give a maximum size for the chunks. How many elements can a single group contain in Dask case?
